# Show that the group $\langle a, b, c | ab = bac \rangle$ is free

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I'm trying to use Tietze transformations tranforms it to the group $\langle a, b, c \rangle$ - is this the right thing to do?

Comment: This won't be possible. The commutator factor group is of rank two. Hence if the group is free it will be free on only two generators (and it is quite easy to see which ones one should take).

Answer (score 3):

It can't be the free group on $3$ generators, since $c$ is completely determined in terms of $a$ and $b$: $c=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. Since you mention Tietze transformations, you can have a look at [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations#Removing_a_generator), which will help you see how to conclude.